# Active class not working on page created by plugin wordpress

Tags: plugins

I'm developing a plugin that creates a post type `"foo"` and a page template `"template-foo.php"`

The problem is the default WordPress active class `current_page_item` is not applied on my page. It is applied on all pages.

When I go to a page "HMP Free" the class is automatically applied on its link

```
<ul>
<li class="page_item page-item-20 current_page_item">
<a href="http://localhost/free/hmp-free/">HMP Free</a>
</li>
<li class="page_item page-item-251">
<a href="http://localhost/free/KBE/">Knowledgebase</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

But when I go to knowledgebase it is not applied on it.

```
<ul>
<li class="page_item page-item-20">
<a href="http://localhost/free/hmp-free/">HMP Free</a>
</li>
<li class="page_item page-item-251">
<a href="http://localhost/free/KBE/">Knowledgebase</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

I don't understand what is going on. I searched about this and found a piece of code but it is not very useful.

```
function add_page_parent_to_single( $classes, $item ) {
    if ( is_single() && $item->title == 'Knowledgebase' ) {
        $classes[] = 'current_page_parent';
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'add_page_parent_to_single', 10, 2 );
```

Please give me some solution ... it is urgent.

Comment: How are you outputting html code for the menu? is it a custom function or wordpress default?

Comment: its an inspect element code